# Dynamically passing a row number to Session.findbyid method

Tags: excel, vba, vbscript, sap-gui

I am trying to write a script which posts invoices in SAP through Excel (fairly new to this), and am running into the following error:

> The control could not be found by id

The error is coming up at the below line:

```
session.FindById("wnd[0]/usr/subITEMS:SAPLFSKB:0100/tblSAPLFSKBTABLE/ctxtACGL_ITEM-HKONT[1,w_counter]").Text = w_glacc
```

Here, I am trying to pass the GL account number in the first row. There can be multiple rows, so I was hoping that instead of passing `ctxtACGL_ITEM-HKONT[1,0]").Text`, `ctxtACGL_ITEM-HKONT[1,1]").Text` etc. I wanted to initialize a counter and pass that value into this method.

Is there any way this can be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution:

Instead of passing just `w_counter` I had to pass `"&w_counter&"`.
Previously, code was:

```
session.FindById("wnd[0]/usr/subITEMS:SAPLFSKB:0100/tblSAPLFSKBTABLE/ctxtACGL_ITEM-HKONT[1,w_counter]").Text = w_glacc
```

Now, it is:

```
session.FindById("wnd[0]/usr/subITEMS:SAPLFSKB:0100/tblSAPLFSKBTABLE/ctxtACGL_ITEM-HKONT[1,"& w_counter &"]").Text = w_glacc
```